# How to Run Anaconda pompt in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm using Anaconda with Python 2.7.14 and spyder 3.2.6 On Ubuntu 14.Can you please suggest me how do I access anaconda promt from Ubuntu? By Anaconda prompt I meant this

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use Anaconda in Ubuntu you only need one terminal of the system.

[Anaconda Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-anaconda-python-distribution-on-ubuntu-16-04)

To see the help commands just type in the terminal

```
conda
```

Answer (score 3):

I have not found out a way to do it exactly but if you are referring to opening a prompt in the context of anaconda as the conda prompt does, you need to create a conda environment then activate and deactivate it as shown below:

```
  conda create -n conda_env1
  conda activate conda_env1 or source activate conda_env1
  conda deactivate
```

Comment: In fedora, anaconda modifies `~/.bashrc` in installation process. After I `source ~/.bashrc`, I get `(base)` in the bash shell command line in terminal.